# Cannot import script from repository in pytest using GitHub actions

Tags: python, github, yaml, pytest, github-actions

I am learning to implement automatic testing using GitHub actions. I am trying to solve the following import error.

The error is:

```py
utils\test_capitalize.py:2: in <module>
    from src.capital import capital_case
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

The structure of my repository is:

```
example/
|-- setup.cfg
|-- setup.py
|-- pyproject.toml
|-- .github/
|   |-- workflows/
|   |   |-- ci.yml
|-- src/
|   |-- capital.py
|-- utils/
|   |-- test_capitalize.py
```

The content of `ci.yml` is:

```yaml
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-test:

    runs-on: windows-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.8]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Build
        run: |
          python -m pip install .
          python -m pip install src
      - name: Test with pytest
        run: |
          python -m pip install pytest
          pytest
```

I thought that `python -m pip install .` already installed all the modules in the repository, do I have a misconception about it?.

Edit: The pytest file is a minimum example (I have tried removing the src before pushing):

```py
import pytest
from src.capital import capital_case


def test_capital_case():
    assert capital_case('semaphore') == 'Semaphore'
```

Comment: You should never have `src` in your input statements.  It should be `from capital import capital_case` in the code.  Remove the `python -m pip install src` line from `ci.yml` too, the line above it is the correct one to use.

Comment: In that case I still have the same problem. The error message is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'capital'`

Comment: I’m guessing it’s not listed in setup.py. Add py_modules=[‘capital’] in the setup call.

Comment: Yes, that was the cause of the issue, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Include these lines in the header of your script before importing the Module.

`import sys`

`sys.path.append("../")`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).